# how to create a "shortcut" in Microsoft Word for frequently used actions

Tags: microsoft-word

for example, one thing I normally do is, select several paragraph of code, set the fonts to Consolas, size to 10, paragraph spacing as 0 for both before and after, then set the shading to "White, Background 1, Darker 5%".

is it a way to set a shortcut for this, e.g. a button on the toolbar or some hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a macro in Word.

1. On the Developer tab, in the Code group, click Record Macro.
2. Click "Begin Recording" and perform the actions you would like to
   the macro the replace.
3. To stop recording your actions, click Stop Recording in the Code
   group.

Refer to this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb) for the full rundown on how to set up the macro, including assigning it a hotkey.

If your needs require finetuning, I recommend using the Visual Basic Editor to modify the actions you need.

Not enough? Try [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), a scripting tool that will allow you to perform even more complex actions and automation.

Comment: it doesn't work -- after clicking "begin Recording", i can't select paragraphs or right click on selected paragraphs to set its fonts etc. but nvm, i think macro is the direction to go. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Select the paragraph once formatted and then create a new paragraph style by going to the Style section on the "Home" tab, click corner arrow and select the icon at the bottom left, per the screenshot: [image]